# Change code inside a .net dll

Tags: .net, reflection, dll, replace

I have a large .net solution with  more than 20 projects. It consists of 1 executable and lots of dll's.

A change to our SOE has broken the app.

I need to be able to open the executable and one dll in say .net reflector (or something similar), change add 3 lines of code  in two places, and then get a recompile of both  files 
Then i will be bale to ship a bug fix,

Can someone point me in the correct direction for this sort of thing?

regards
Buzz

Comment: It is not possible as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the correct track. After opening your problematic .dll(s) in .NET Reflector or your chosen .dll decompiler, you should be able to extract the source code and edit in visual studio (or whatever editor you choose to use). After finishing your edits, you will then have to recompile the code and your .dll should be ready to go. I hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

If the assembly is signed (strong-name assembly), you need to resign it with the same key used in development. Otherwise this should work.